# ActionScript 3 Parsing XML From Website

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing

I have tried may example I found here and on the new (Google).
Nothing seems to work.

I have a XML file which I get after a call to a website:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso8859-1" ?>
<Database version="1.24" xmlns="http://1234.com">
  <Session>
    <Key>1234</Key>
    <Count>2424</Count>
    <SubExp>Sun Dec  1 00:00:00 2013</SubExp>
    <GMTime>Thu Feb  7 19:38:03 2013</GMTime>
    <Remark>cpu: 0.058s</Remark>
  </Session>
</Database>
```

OK I loaded into a XML object like so:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
```

Good so far the object contains the XML data:

```
<Database version="1.24" xmlns="http://1234.com">
      <Session>
        <Key>1234</Key>
        <Count>2424</Count>
        <SubExp>Sun Dec  1 00:00:00 2013</SubExp>
        <GMTime>Thu Feb  7 19:38:03 2013</GMTime>
        <Remark>cpu: 0.058s</Remark>
      </Session>
    </Database>
```

now I need to read the key value under session so I have tried :

```
xml.Session.Key
xml.Session[0].Key
xml[0].Session.Key
```

some of them returns a empty string some just errors either way no data?

so in the Expression window I typed xml[0][0] just to see what happens.

and it returns the key value, however when I place it in my code

```
var key:String = xml[0][0];
trace(key):
```

the trace returns the whole XML file?
so I'm not sure what I might be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the namespace.

Try this:

```
var xml:XML = new XML(event.target.data);
var ns:Namespace = xml.namespace();
trace(xml.ns::Session.ns::Key);
```

Also, this can be a bad idea, but when I just want some data and don't care about the namespaces (or they aren't relevant to what I'm doing) I have this handy function to strip them out and return an XML object without them:

```
public function stripNamespaces(xml:XML):XML {

    const DECLARATION_REG_EXP:RegExp = new RegExp("xmlns[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\"", "gi");

    var namespaceDeclarations:Array = xml.namespaceDeclarations();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < namespaceDeclarations.length; i++) {
        xml.removeNamespace(namespaceDeclarations[i]);
    }

    return new XML(xml.toString().replace(DECLARATION_REG_EXP, ""));        
}
```

Comment: Nice, you beat me by a few seconds :) I wasn't aware of this type of syntax... Was about to delete my answer, but I'll leave it as it might  be a little more concise if they want to use a lot of e4x expressions.

Comment: Sunil your solution will work as well, though you will run into problems when you are using multiple xml objects that have different namespaces.

Comment: Neat! Thanks for explaining that (wish I could upvote twice).

Comment: Work great I have to remember about the namespace item. Also thanks for the function...

Answer (score 0):

Since your xml has a namespace, you need to tell Flash/e4x to use it:

```
private var xml:XML =
    <Database version="1.24" xmlns="http://1234.com">
      <Session>
        <Key>1234</Key>
        <Count>2424</Count>
        <SubExp>Sun Dec  1 00:00:00 2013</SubExp>
        <GMTime>Thu Feb  7 19:38:03 2013</GMTime>
        <Remark>cpu: 0.058s</Remark>
      </Session>
    </Database>;

private function onCreationComplete():void
{
    namespace myNameSpace = "http://1234.com";
    use namespace myNameSpace;
    var value:String = xml.Session.Key;
    trace("value:", value); // outputs: value: 1234
}
```